# In Crichton's 'Prey', why don't the protagonists take the appropriate precautionary measures when dealing with the antagonist?

Tags: prey-novel

I tried to write the heading to not contain any **spoilers**, which I am not going to attempt for the body post. You have been warned.

In the middle third of the [book](http://1.droppdf.com/files/pd6he/prey-michael-crichton.pdf), the antagonist is a cloud of bacteria, which kills by entering the airways of the victim and deposits toxins. This is known to all the protagonists nearly from the start:

> “The lungs are bright pink
>   and
>   firm,
>   normal
>   appearance.” She cut one lobe
>   with the scalpel, then again,
>   and again. Finally she exposed the bronchial tube,
>   and cut it open. It was dark
>   black on the inside.
>
> “**Bronchi show heavy
>   infestation with nanoparticles**
>   consistent with inhalation of
>   swarm elements,” she said,
>   dictating. “You getting this,
>   Bobby?”
>
> “Getting it all. Video
>   resolution is good.”
>
> She continued to cutupward.
>   “Following
>   the
>   bronchial tree toward the
>   throat ...”
>   And she continued cutting,
>   into the throat, and then from
>   the nose back across the
>   cheek, then opening the
>   mouth ... I had to turn away
>   for a moment. But she
>   continued calmly to dictate.
>   “I am observing heavy
>   infiltration of all the nasal
>   passages and pharynx. **This is suggestive of partial or full
>   airway obstruction, which in
>   turn may indicate the cause of
>   death.**”

Furthermore, all the protagonists are represented as highly intelligent, with some of them being trained in the field of biology.

However, in every possible encounter with the "wild strain", they approach it as if fighting a lion and not bacteria:

> As I pulled my shirt
>   over my head, the headsetcame away, falling to the
>   ground. And then, holding the
>   shirt in my hand, I swung it in
>   broad
>   whooshing
>   arcs
>   through
>   the
>   air.
>   And
>   **screaming like a banshee**, I
>   charged the swarm by the
>   door.
>
> ...
>
> “You had a lot of trouble
>   breathing.”
>   “I still do.” I reached for a
>   Kleenex and **blew my nose. A
>   lot of black stuff came out**,
>   mixed with blood and dust
>   from the desert. I had to blow
>   my nose four or five times to
>   clear it.

Later:

> “Which means?”
>   “We flock,” I said.
>   Charley gave a horse
>   laugh. “Yeah, right, we flock
>   —and pray like hell!”
>   “I’m serious,” I said.

It seems that biohazard measures would have been more appropriate in those situations.

- The plant surely has some hazmat suits.
- Failing that, a plastic bag over the head would give anyone the needed couple of minutes of time to get back to the safety of the main building.
- Failing that, just holding one's breath or exhaling slowly like a swimmer, as opposed to "screaming like a banshee" would reduce the amount of foreign bodies inhaled.

Is there some in-universe explanation for this behaviour?

Comment: I doubt you can "exhale slowly" with enough force to keep the swarm from flying upstream into your nose. Using a shirt to swat them away (like flies) seems like the best option if you don't have a hazmat suit. I assumed that screaming like banshee was a combination of psyching himself up (like a battle cry) and just panicking.

Answer (score 2):

The particles have a degree of networked intelligence and ability to actively move. They also act as a swarm more than as individuals.

The plant might have hazmat suits, but I don't recall them being mentioned explicitly. Once they were outside without them, they wouldn't be an option to return in.

Plastic bag over the head would give at most one or two breaths so would need to be removed soon after the time simple breath holding would apply. It also wouldn't give a seal around the neck that would stop ingress of particles.

Breath hold or slow exhalation might delay passive movement of a normal bacterium, but these were powered and actively moving; they could enter the respiratory tract.

In the absence of a way to defeat the physical characteristics of the individual particles they found a way to defeat the swarm as a whole by taking advantage of its programming.